# Is an offset singular for a kafka's topic replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka's consumer reads from some partition, which has replicas. After consumer's acknowledge the offset is updated.
Is the offset updated for the all partition's replicas?

Comment: Offsets should only be valid for the leader partitions of any topic, although consumers can be configured to fetch from replicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset is updated only for a partition, not it's replicas.
Let's say we have a topic we 5 partitions and RF of 3 which is being consumed by a consumer.

A consumer will connect to only one of the replica of each partition to read data from (by default it will connect to leader of the each 5 partitions) and once it reads the message from the partitions - the offset will be updated for each of the 5 partitions (not each and every replicas of each partition).